# Comparing two condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $\rho:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ be a measurable function.

The condition 1 for the function $\rho$ is: There exist constants $C_1>0$ and $0<2k_1<k_2<\infty$ such that
$$
\sup_{r/2<s\le r}\rho(s)\leq C_1 \int_{k_1 r}^{k_2 r}\frac{\rho(s)}{s}ds,\qquad r>0.
$$

The condition 2 for the function $\rho$ is: There exist constant $C_2>0$ such that 
$$
\frac{1}{C_2}\le \frac{\rho(r)}{\rho(s)}\le C_2
$$
whenever $r$ and $s$ satisfy 
$$
r,s>0 \text{   and   }\frac{1}{2}\le \frac{r}{s}\le 2.
$$
The claim is "conditon 1 is weaker than condition 2, i.e., condition 2 implies condition 1."

I can not prove this claim. Can anybody help me to prove this claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 2 implies that

$$\rho(s) \leqslant C_2 \rho(r)$$

for $\frac{r}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant r$, from which

$$\sup_{\frac{r}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant r} \rho(s) \leqslant C_2 \rho(r)$$

follows immediately. On the other hand, choosing $k_2 = 1$ and $0 < k_1 < \frac{1}{2}$ yields

\begin{align}
\int_{k_1r}^{k_2r} \frac{\rho(s)}{s}\,ds
&> \int_{r/2}^r \frac{\rho(s)}{s}\,ds \\
&\geqslant \frac{\rho(r)}{C_2}\int_{r/2}^r \frac{ds}{s} \\
&= \frac{\log 2}{C_2}\rho(r)
\end{align}

using the inequality

$$\rho(s) \geqslant \frac{\rho(r)}{C_2}$$

for $\frac{r}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant r$ implied by condition 2. Putting both pieces together, we have

$$\sup_{\frac{r}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant r} \rho(s) \leqslant C_1 \int_{k_1r}^{k_2r} \frac{\rho(s)}{s}\,ds$$

with

$$C_1 = \frac{C_2^2}{\log 2}$$

and $0 < 2k_1 < k_2 = 1 < \infty$, that is, we have condition 1.